# Remove individual points and output slope python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I am trying to delete one pair of x and y coordinates from a set of 10 data points and get the slope for the other 9 points.

How do I go about this issue?

Attached herewith is an image of what I am trying to figure out:

[image: Data]

In the above image, column B is x-axis and column C is y-axis.

Column D has multiple slopes for every datapoint removed.

The comment section says how each slope was obtained.

Example: Slope of 0.3741 was obtained by removing out B6 and C6 from the dataset.

This is an extremely challenging topic for me to figure out which path to follow. Any help on this aspect is deeply appreciated.

---

The code I am using to find overall slope for both x and y axis is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_excel('Slope.xlsx')

x = df['x-axis']
y = df['y-axis']

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
print(slope)
```

---

It is similar to go find a pair of x and y coordinates, delete the pair and then give the slope of the remaining 9 points.

---

Thanks for reading.

A newbie in python and thus difficult to find some path to follow on this topic.

Comment: How do you do it with all the points?

Comment: @Goyo, I added the code which I use to find he overall slope for all the points.

Comment: Now all you have to do is figuring out how to delete a specific row in a `DataFrame`. Pandas has excellent documentation so it should be a piece of cake.

Comment: @Goyo, any link to the way it needs to be done? I am unable to find a method which suits the way I need the final output to be.

Comment: Does [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) do what you need?

Comment: Goyo, apologies I tried but may be not sure how to use it. The output is what @SpghttCd has obtained. Only difference is I need it via pandas framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-program-best-fit-line-slope-machine-learning-tutorial/

This page may be helpful for you if you are looking for best-fit slope.

To get the slope for 9 of the 10 points.

```
xs = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], dtype=np.float64)
ys = np.array([5,4,6,5,6,4,5,6,7,5], dtype=np.float64)
slope = []

for n in range (0,9):
    tmp_x = np.delete(xs,n)
    tmp_y = np.delete(ys,n)
    slope[n] = best_fit_slope(tmp_x,tmp_y)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I checked it and it gives only one slope. That is easy to do. Iterating/looping is challenging.

Comment: If you've got the function ready, all you need is to repeatedly call the function with different x,y array. 
numpy.delete(a, index) should allow you to remove certain index from the array.

Comment: looking for a pandas solution

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try this:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.randint(0, 25, 10)
y = np.random.randint(0, 25, 10)

print(x, y)

for i, pair in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
    m, t = np.polyfit(np.delete(x, i), np.delete(y, i), 1)
    print('slope', m, 'for data without pair', i, ':', pair)
```

As far as I see, a `pandas` solution could look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x, y]).T, columns=['x', 'y'])

df['m'], df['t'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.polyfit(df.x.drop(row.name), df.y.drop(row.name), 1), axis=1).T.values

print(df)
```

Comment: this works great!!! It is using np library. The code I am focussing on uses pandas framework. Any help with the pandas version of the same output?

Comment: how to get the same output using Pandas? The output you getting is exactly what I need.